# The site does not work with black black background

Tags: bug, design

The default browser window doesn't need to be white. 
And if your default color is black it's hard to work with the site.

**screenshot**
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You should break this into a question and answer.

Comment: @goldilocks good point!

Comment: @Gilles why do you think this is a feature and not a bug?

Comment: @Sirl33tname Because the sites are not intended to be viewed with arbitrary style changes. If you change the style, you're on your own.

Comment: related: second from the bottom of the Design section of http://catb.org/~esr/html-hell.html

Comment: @Gilles I'm going to have to disagree on this one, this is a bug. Any site that explicitly sets a text color instead of relying on defaults should also set the background. The trouble seems te be the transparent pattern image has been laid over what is assumed to be a white background, but that is not a safe assumption according to spec. This is not a case of applying a custom style (e.g. using a userstyle utility) but of having different browser defaults (which some OS themes specify).

Comment: `you change the style` no and thats the point why this is a bug, black is the default window color and just because 99% has the default color white you shoudn't trust on that

Answer (score 3):

The solution is easy, just set the html background-color explicit to white and everything is as expected. (like on stackoverflow)

Comment: Why is this site different from stackoverflow?

Comment: Good question, but I really don't know.

Comment: I don't understand. You set your default background to black and, obviously, can't see a site that uses black as its default font color, so you set your background to white and solve the problem you created. Why set it to black in the first place? You'll have the same problem with most of the internet!

Comment: No, the most site do this explicit. It's a bad practise, to hope that the browser maybe do the right thing, when you can set this explicit.